# All lines itemized when mark is active

Tags: itemize, emacs, auctex

In AUCTeX I would like the behaviour of `LaTeX-environment` and/or `LaTeX-insert-item` to create multiple items for *every* line when called with mark active.

Comment: To be clear: you want to mark a region and wrap it with an `itemize`-like environment and put an `\item` at the beginning of every line?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood what you want, the following code should do the trick:

```lisp
(defadvice LaTeX-env-item
  (around LaTeX-env-item-region activate)
  "When there is an active region, wrap the environment around it.
Insert \\item macros at the beginning of every non empty line of the region."
  (let ((beg (min (point) (mark)))
    (if (< (point) (mark))
    (exchange-point-and-mark))
    (save-excursion
      (while (re-search-backward "^\\(.+\\)$" beg t)
    (replace-match "\\\\item \\1" t nil)
    (beginning-of-line 1))))
  ad-do-it
  ;; Remove the extra \item.
  (re-search-forward "\\\\item " (save-excursion (end-of-line)) t)
  (replace-match ""))
```

This works with all environments inserted with `LaTeX-env-item`, i.e. `enumerate`, `itemize`, `trivlist`, `description`, and `theindex` by default.

Comment: Great! I fixed your code so it works both when point < mark and vice versa.

Comment: BTW: Do you know of any way  to automatically insert `[<+->]` arguments to the `itemize` environment when I'm in a beamer frame so I get pretty incremental display during presentation?

Comment: @Nordlöw ask a new question, I have already the answer `;-)`.

Comment: Ok. Great. Here's the new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161784/automatically-insert-environment-arguments