# Automatically Insert Environment Arguments

Tags: beamer, environments, optional-arguments

How can I automatically insert `[<+->]` arguments to the `itemize` environment when I'm in a `beamer` frame so I get pretty incremental display during presentation?

Comment: Maybe the {auctex} tag should be removed!?

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\item bar
\item baz
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh! That simple.

Comment: @Nordlöw Well, I think the AUCTeX-dependent solution isn't needed anymore `:-)`.